# D3.js - Get a random point within an arc

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, charts, pie-chart

How would one attempt to get a random coordinate within an existing arc?

I am currently rendering a piechart from user data and would like to render a number of points on each arc at random locations - they may be outside of their arc, however

At the moment, I am using a random deviation (within a certain range) from the centroid of each arc. This approach is problematic as arcs might be too small and points end up outside of their arc.

I can't really provide any example code at the moment as I am really just rendering a pie chart with five slices so far.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your current code. That will help us answer your question. See also [ask]. Also, what version of d3 are you using? There are massive differences between v3 and the newest v6

Comment: I am using d3.js 6.2.0
I'll try to come up with a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/adamjanes/5e53cfa2ef3d3f05828020315a3ba18c) as a starting point. What I did was generate 10 times 2 numbers for every arc: a distance from the centre and an angle (in radians). Then I plotted the circles using those values.

To show that it works, I made the radius constant, so you see a circle of black dots. If you want, you can use the commented out line to make that random as well.

Note how the circles are the same colour as the arcs.

I also had to subtract `Math.PI / 2`, because of the different zero points between degrees and radians:

- 0 degrees is a vertical line to the top;
- 0 radians is a horizontal line to the right. `-Math.PI / 2` radians is a vertical line to the top.

```js
const data = [{
    "region": "North",
    "count": "53245"
  },
  {
    "region": "South",
    "count": "28479"
  },
  {
    "region": "East",
    "count": "19697"
  },
  {
    "region": "West",
    "count": "24037"
  },
  {
    "region": "Central",
    "count": "40245"
  }
];

const width = 360;
const height = 360;
const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

const svg = d3.select("#chart-area")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2})`);

const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#66c2a5", "#fc8d62", "#8da0cb",
  "#e78ac3", "#a6d854", "#ffd92f"
]);

const pie = d3.pie()
  .value(d => d.count)
  .sort(null);

const arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(0)
  .outerRadius(radius);

// Join new data
const path = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(pie(data));

// Enter new arcs
path.enter().append("path")
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("stroke", "white")
  .attr("stroke-width", "6px")
  .each(drawPoints);

function drawPoints(d, i) {
  // Generate random numbers (x, y) where x between startAngle
  // and endAngle
  // and y between 0 and radius
  const points = new Array(10).fill(undefined).map(() => ({
    angle: d.startAngle + Math.random() * (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) - Math.PI / 2,
    //radius: Math.random() * radius,
    radius: radius / 2,
  }));

  svg.selectAll(`.point-${i}`)
    .data(points)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('class', `point point-${i}`)
    .attr("fill", (d) => color(i))
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', '2px')
    .attr('cx', (d) => d.radius * Math.cos(d.angle))
    .attr('cy', (d) => d.radius * Math.sin(d.angle))
    .attr('r', 3)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.js"></script>
<div id="chart-area"></div>
```

Comment: That is actually exactly what I was looking for and I can work with this. Thank you! I apologize for not providing a proper example.

Comment: Don't worry about it, asking questions is just as much of a skill as programming